# binding segmented button with master view list in sapui5

Tags: javascript, xml, model-view-controller, sapui5

I want to bind segmented button in the master view list in the split container of SAPUI5 Apllication.

This is my view :

```
<SegmentedButton>
    <Button press="onSegButtonPress" selected="true" text="Products"/>
    <Button press="add_cust" text="Customer"/>
</SegmentedButton>
<List id="list1" items="{path:'/CustomerMaster'}">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem type="Active" press="onListItemPress" number="{price}" title="{name}"/>
    </items>
</List>
```

This is my code snippet from my controller at present.

What do I write in the controller for event onSegButtonPress? And what changes do I need to make in the existing methods?

```
onInit: function() {
    var omodel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    omodel.loadData("model/model.json");
    this.getView().byId("list1").setModel(omodel);
},
onSegButtonPress: function() {

},

onListItemPress: function(oEvent) {
    this.showDetails1(oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath());
},

showDetails1: function(detailPath) {
    var omodel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    omodel.loadData("model/model.json");
    this.getView().setModel(omodel);
    this.getView().bindElement({
        path: detailPath
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to load the items in the list after clicking on the segmented button.

Comment: Aren't they already loaded? You did the model binding in the onInit, which gets called very early.

Comment: Yes, they are already loaded. But I want to load the list items after I click on that button.

Comment: Then why don't you move the onInit code to your button handler